# Parse text file which groups data

Tags: python, parsing

Trying to figure out how to extract strings and put into new file on new line for each string

Can't get my head around RegEx and all the things I'm looking at online show the data all being on one line but mine is already separated.

Trying to parse the output of another program, it outputs three lines `Date,Address,Name` and then has a newline and another set of three and I only need Address.

```
fo = open("C:\Sampledata.txt", "r")

item = fo.readlines(
```

Not even got anything working yet!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this addesses your problem, but maybe something like:

```
addresses = list()

with open("file1", "r") as input:
    for line in input:
        if line.startswith("Address"):
            addresses.append(line.strip("\n"))
```

Edit: Or if "Adress" is only contained once per file you can break the loop after detecting the line starting with "Address":

```
addresses = list()

with open("file1", "r") as input:
    for line in input:
        if line.startswith("Address"):
            addresses.append(line.strip("\n"))
            break
```

Then you can write all adresses into a new file.

```
with open("newFile", "w") as outfile:
    for adress in addresses:
        outfile.write(adress + "\n")
```

Comment: that script works but im dealing with 10mb files and it seems to take forever, can it be made faster?

Comment: Your initial question sounded as it was only 3 lines of content, newline, another 3 lines of content...
If "Address" is only contained once per file you can add a "break" to stop the line-loop

Comment: yes it does, and there is probably about 10,000 lines

Comment: break stops the loop, so as soon as a line starting with "Address" is found, the file will not futher be read.

Comment: okay, will that not just stop the program from executing? maybe i didnt explain well enough, the txt file has thousands of addresses, i need those putting into a new text file with one address per line

Comment: Okay, as I wrote two times now, you can only do the break if address is only contained once per file - if it's contained more than one time you will have to read out the whole document, so you can not use break and have to stick to the initial answer

Comment: ok thanks for the answer, it does work but not really what im looking for, as it takes far too long, is there a way to write every line of output one by one so the output can be worked on periodically?

Comment: You can easily split the original document when working with bash under Linux
e.g. split -l 10000 filename
This will split the original file into many files with each maximum 10000 lines of text

Comment: the break version isnt working as expected as it doesnt write any file as output, should find the first address quickly and put into file with one line.

Comment: of course you have to put the code for writing the new file too.
So the code that opens the outfile...

Comment: yes ive added the second piece of code you had in your answer directly below the first

Comment: when i say it works what i mean is it doesnt error when executing the file, but nothing happens so not sure it qualifies as working

Comment: Well, as you can see in the code there is an output file written containing all addreses and it is called newFile.
Here you can of course specify any path and filename you want or maybe give it an ending like ".txt" so that you can just double-click it to to open it on windows...

Answer (score 0):

```
outList = []
inText = open("C:\Sampledata.txt", "r").read()
for line in inText.split("\n"):
    Date,Address,Name = line.split(",")
    outList .append(Address)

outText = "\n".join(outList )
open("outFile.txt","w").write(outText )
```